# Possible to download/add a snapin from PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I am writing a script that uses the [Quest ActiveRoles Management Shell](http://www.quest.com/powershell/activeroles-server.aspx) and I plan on handing this off to other people I work with to use.  Before I started using this snapin on my Dev machine I had to go to their website, download the MSI, install it and then use `Add-PSSnapin` to make it available.

Is there anyways I can include these steps in my script so that users don't have to do it themselves?  Seems like it is a big security risk, so I'm not sure if it can even be done.

Answer (score 1):

I agree that it sounds like a bit of a security risk.  Have you tried simply automating the steps?  This should get you started.  (Note that you'll have to provide values for the variables)

Download the installer:

```
$web=new-object net.webclient
$web.DownloadFile($URL,$tempdirectory)
```

Run the installer:

```
& "$tempdirectory\$nameofmsifile"
```

Add the snapin

```
add-pssnapin "Name of Snapin"
```

Comment: No i haven't tried that (sorry, i'm new to PowerShell).  Looks promising, I'll give it a shot